# User aync-await in the react-redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to the `react-redux` . Here I am trying to use the `aysnc-await` . What I have is on componentDidMount I am calling an api in which if there I got `200 Ok` then and then only I want to call the second api. so I am using the `async-await` for this.

```
export function fetchUserResumes(pageNo, jdId) {
  pageNo = 0;
  let size = 20;
  return (dispatch) => {
    const page = `page=${pageNo}`;
    let url = FETCH_RESUMES + '/' + jdId + '?' + page + '&' + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    return get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_RESUME_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload
          })
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
        } else {
          if (!response.status) {
            toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
          }
          else if (response.status.status === 401) {
            dispatch(logout());
          }
          else if (response.status.status === 500) {
            toastr.error("Error while fetching Job description,Please try again");
            dispatch({
              type: FETCHING_RESUME_FAILED,
              data: response.status,
            });
            dispatch({
              type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
            })
          } else {
            dispatch({
              type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
            })
          }
        }
        return true;
      })
  }
};
```

The action which is getting called on didmout is

```
export function getUserJobInfo(jobId) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    });
    let url = GET_JOB_INFO_URL + jobId;
    let response = await get(url);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      let pageNo = 0;
      let size = 20;
      const page = `page=${pageNo}`;
      let url = FETCH_RESUMES + '/' + jobId + '?' + page + '&' + size;
      let newApiResponse = await get(dispatch(fetchUserResumes(pageNo, jobId)));
      dispatch({
        type: USER_JOB_INFO,
        data: response.payload
      })
    }
    else {
    }
  }
}
```

This is the way which I tried to do this. But here I am getting very confused while using the async await.So can any one help me with this to resolve this. 
Thanks.

Comment: `get(dispatch(fetchUserResumes` this `get` seems invalid. What does it expect in args and what is the dispatch return? I think you don't need `get` here. Just remove it. Dispatch will pass promise return from fetch method

Comment: yes that is wrong

Comment: So, what should be the structure of this methid ?

Comment: await (dispatch(fetchUserResumes(pageNo, jobId)));   used this in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `get` on `await get(dispatch(fetchUserResumes(pageNo, jobId)));`.

In the case of thunk, `dispatch` returns the same that returns internal function. So in your case, return type of this dispatch would be `Promise`. And `await` works with any promises.

```
  let newApiResponse = await dispatch(fetchUserResumes(pageNo, jobId));
```